# WPF custom slider PART_SelectionRange lags behind the thumb

Tags: c#, wpf, styles

I've created custom slider and thumb templates for my app. It's working as expected except for the PART_SelectionRange Rectangle, which begins slightly behind the thumb and by the time the maximum value is reached is noticeably far behind it.

I have no clue how this could be fixed since it looks like the problem is in the behaviour of whatever class is controlling the size of the PART_SelectionRange Rectangle.

[image: This video illustrates the problem] (Sorry, I don't know how to inline it).

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="SliderThumbHorizontalDefault" TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
    <Grid>
        <!-- SliderThumb -->
        <Path x:Name="grip" Data="M-0.4,6.4 C1.2,1 9,1 10.5,6.5 12,11.787571 5.0267407,18.175417 5.0267407,18.175417 5.0267407,18.175417 -2,11.8 -0.4,6.4 z"
            Fill="White" Stretch="Fill" SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
            Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1" UseLayoutRounding="True" />
        <ContentPresenter Margin="0 4 0 0"  Content="{Binding Value, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Slider}}}" TextBlock.Foreground="Black" TextBlock.FontSize="20" TextBlock.TextAlignment="Center" />
    </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>

<ControlTemplate x:Key="SliderHorizontal" TargetType="{x:Type Slider}">
    <ControlTemplate.Resources>
        <vc:TickConverter x:Key="TickConverter" />
    </ControlTemplate.Resources>
    <Grid Height="{StaticResource SliderHeight}">
        <Border x:Name="TrackBackground" BorderBrush="{StaticResource SliderThumb.Track.Border}" BorderThickness="0"
                Background="White"
                CornerRadius="{Binding ActualHeight, Converter={StaticResource HalvingConverter}, ElementName=TrackBackground}">
            <!-- This rectangle is what lags behind! -->
            <Rectangle x:Name="PART_SelectionRange" Fill="SlateBlue"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Left" RadiusY="3" RadiusX="3" />
        </Border>
        <Track x:Name="PART_Track" >
            <Track.Thumb>
                <Thumb x:Name="Thumb" Focusable="False" Width="35" Height="47" OverridesDefaultStyle="True"
                            Template="{StaticResource SliderThumbHorizontalDefault}" Margin="-14.65,-55,-16,12"/>
            </Track.Thumb>
        </Track>
    </Grid>
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsSelectionRangeEnabled" Value="true">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="PART_SelectionRange" Value="Visible" />
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocused" Value="true">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" TargetName="Thumb" Value="Blue" />
        </Trigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>

<Style TargetType="{x:Type Slider}">
    <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="{StaticResource SliderHeight}" />
    <Setter Property="MaxHeight" Value="{StaticResource SliderHeight}" />
    <Setter Property="Stylus.IsPressAndHoldEnabled" Value="false" />
    <Setter Property="IsSelectionRangeEnabled" Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource SliderThumb.Static.Foreground}" />
    <Setter Property="SelectionStart" Value="{Binding Minimum, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" />
    <Setter Property="SelectionEnd" Value="{Binding Value, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" />
    <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource SliderHorizontal}" />
</Style>
```

At this point I don't know what I should be trying to modify. I believe I've tried changing every property that made sense from xaml, so I think the problem is in the Slider class, but can't fathom where.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you cannot change this behavior of the `Slider` just using custom `Style`s and `ControlTemplate`s.

The reason is that the `Slider` control adjusts the width of the selection range according to the width of the `Thumb`. This causes the selection range bar to "hang back" while you're moving the slider position towards its `Maximum` value. If you'd like the selection range to exactly follow the `Value`, you'd need to set the `Thumb` width to 0. But then, obviously, you won't be able to move the thumb since there will be no hit testing anymore.

This is the [current implementation](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/Framework/System/Windows/Controls/Slider.cs,929cdc94610e9204,references) of the corresponding selection range size and position adjustments:

```
if (DoubleUtil.AreClose(range, 0d) || (DoubleUtil.AreClose(trackSize.Width, thumbSize.Width)))
{
    valueToSize = 0d;
}
else
{
    valueToSize = Math.Max(0.0, (trackSize.Width - thumbSize.Width) / range);
}

rangeElement.Width = ((SelectionEnd - SelectionStart) * valueToSize);
if (IsDirectionReversed)
{
    Canvas.SetLeft(rangeElement, (thumbSize.Width * 0.5) + Math.Max(Maximum - SelectionEnd, 0) * valueToSize);
}
else
{
    Canvas.SetLeft(rangeElement, (thumbSize.Width * 0.5) + Math.Max(SelectionStart - Minimum, 0) * valueToSize);
}
```

You have two options now:

- implement your own slider control that doesn't adjust its selection range according to the `Thumb` width
- or remove the `"PART_SelectionRange"` name from the selection rectangle in your `ControlTemplate` and use `Binding`s with `IValueConverter`s (or `Behavior`s, or attached properties) to control the appearance manually

Answer (score 1):

Following @dymanoid 's answer, I implemented the behaviour manually (after failing to create a new slider).

I removed the PART_SelectionRange control (had to make it transparent or it wouldn't compile) replacing it by this other rectangle.

```
<Border x:Name="TrackBackground" BorderBrush="{StaticResource SliderThumb.Track.Border}" BorderThickness="0"
        Background="{StaticResource SliderThumb.Track.Background}"
        CornerRadius="{Binding ActualHeight, Converter={StaticResource HalvingConverter}, ElementName=TrackBackground}">
    <Rectangle x:Name="SelectionRange" Fill="{StaticResource SliderThumb.Track.BackgroundSelected}"
                HorizontalAlignment="Left" RadiusY="3" RadiusX="3">
        <Rectangle.Width>
            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource SliderToSelectionWidthConverter}">
                <Binding Path="Value" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}"/>
                <Binding Path="Maximum" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}"/>
                <Binding Path="Minimum" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}"/>
                <Binding Path="ActualWidth" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}"/>
            </MultiBinding>
        </Rectangle.Width>
    </Rectangle> 
</Border>
```

The relevant thing is that its width is bound to the Slider's Value, Minimum, Maximum and ActualWidth properties. Using this converter:

```
class SliderToSelectionWidthConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var Value = (double) values[0];
        var Minimum = (double) values[1];
        var Maximum = (double) values[2];
        var ActualWidth = (double) values[3];
        return (1 - (Value - Minimum) / (Maximum - Minimum)) * ActualWidth;
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

those values can be used to compute the real width of the SelectionRange rectangle. Why this is not done in the default Slider is beyond me.